# Flash / Facebook - Dynamically adding cross domain policy to SWF?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, facebook

We're building an app that loads a user's photos from facebook. It seems facebook hosts these images across multiple hosts. Is it possible to dynamically add a cross domain policy, after a Security sandbox violation has occurred?

For example...

```
try
{
    // Load the photo passed from the js method
}
catch (SecuritySandboxViolation Exception:e)
{       
    /*

    Transform the exception message which contains the host url from...

    "security error: Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: http://canvas-app.domain.com/SWF.swf cannot load data from security error: Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: http://facebook.tombstone.com/halloween-party-kit/GI_2011_09_TOMBSTONE_SPOOKIFY.swf cannot load data from https://s-hphotos-sjc1.fbcdn.net/229411_989116685126_5519474_47232933_4376850_n.jpg.22421_989116685126_5519474_47232933_4376850_n.jpg."

    to...

    https://s-hphotos-sjc1.fbcdn.net    

    */

    var host = e.getMessage();

    // *magical string transformation*

    Security.loadPolicyFile(host)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If facebook hasn't put a crossdomain on their site, loadPolicyFile won't work.

However, what are you using to load the images? Usually, you don't need crossdomain.xml if you only want to display images.

---

**Edit**

https://s-hphotos-sjc1.fbcdn.net has a permissive crossdomain, so the problem seems to be in how the image is being loaded. Try setting `LoaderContext.checkPolicyFile = true` for the `Loader`.

Comment: Exactly you only need a crossdomain policy if you're attempting to load and execute additional swfs over multiple domains.

Comment: @Jacob: We need to perform pixel manipulation on the image. This requires us to use a load method that is effected by cross-domain policies. Is it possible to dynamically load cross domain files?

Comment: @John perhaps you can update your question with more details, because if you're requiring a crossdomain policy file just for loading pictures, then there is something seriously wrong. You should not require one. You should be able to load the images with the Loader object or the raw binary data using URLLoader with the properties set URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY (I believe something like that, I havn't actually written any as3 in months.)

Comment: @Ascension. If you're doing byte manipulation, you can require a crossdomain. Though there are some techniques to avoid the need in most cases.

Comment: @John can you give some more details on how you are loading the images? (https://s-hphotos-sjc1.fbcdn.net has a permissive crossdomain.xml, so that shouldn't be a problem in any case unless something out of the ordinary is going on.)

Comment: @Jacob I think you're referring to the case where you use the Loader object combined with executable bytes? I've never heard of requiring any policy to simply load images into a bitmap object.

Comment: @Ascension see [LoaderContext.checkPolicyFile](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html#checkPolicyFile) It specifically references images when "...you expect to need access to the content of that image from ActionScript."

Comment: Interesting thanks for the reference, was unaware. Been outa the flash game for quite a long time, I guess now it's showing lol.

Answer (score 1):

What's more likely the issue, is that within your SWF that is embedded in or actually is the app, you are not defining your own crossdomain policy. You need to do this either explicitly with AS3 code or put up a crossdomain policy on your own domain, the domain that is hosting your SWF file. Facebook is probably being restricted in what it can do with your SWF when it loads it, because of a lack of specification within your policy file, or it's missing all together. Remember the direction of things. You're not loading facebook with your SWF, facebook is loading your SWF. (Note also that Jacobs answer is correct too).